# How to show the markers, some distance from the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, distance

In google maps the markers are shown by default from the farthest distance
like this:

[image: ph1]

What I'm looking for is to display the markers only at a certain distance for example at this distance:
[image]

Comment: Add more default zoom into map during loading so that the markers will get spread out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `List<Marker> markers` to store your created markers:

```
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
```

and check whether they need to be visible on each camera change:

```
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            if (googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom > 18) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
});

//Add some markers:
markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-1.052375, -78.128102))));
markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-1.054864, -78.153422))));
markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-1.072542, -78.102010))));
```